# python does not solve an ode system properly

Tags: python, ode

I have an ODE which I need to solve and plot. This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy import integrate


##############################
# Constants
#α = 1,β = 12,μ = 0.338,Vb = 0.01,ω = 0.5,
alpha = 1#p1
beta = 12#p2
mu = 0.338#p3

omega = 0.5#p5
gamma = 0.25#p6
Acoef=0.5
tmax = 1000
t = np.arange(0.0, tmax, 0.001)
################################
# Initial conditions vector

X0=0
I0=0
Z0=0.06
H0=0.04
E0=0
O0=0.02
# The  model differential equations.
def deriv(y,t):
    X, I, Z, H, E, O = y
    dXdt = I
    dIdt = -(alpha)*(X)-(beta)*(X**3)-(mu)*I+gamma*(1/(1-X)**2)-gamma*(1/(1+X)**2)+Acoef*(1/(1-X)**2)*(np.sin(omega*t))
    dZdt = H
    dHdt =-(alpha)*(Z)-(beta)*(Z**3)-(mu)*I+gamma*(1/(1-Z)**2)-gamma*(1/(1+Z)**2)+Acoef*(1/(1-Z)**2)*(np.sin(omega*t))
    dEdt=O
    dOdt=-(alpha)*(X)-(beta)*(X**3)-(mu)*I+gamma*(1/(1-X)**2)-gamma*(1/(1+X)**2)+Acoef*(1/(1-X)**2)*(np.sin(omega*t))-(-(alpha)*(Z)-(beta)*(Z**3)-(mu)*I+gamma*(1/(1-Z)**2)-gamma*(1/(1+Z)**2)+Acoef*(1/(1-Z)**2)*(np.sin(omega*t)))
    return dXdt, dIdt, dZdt, dHdt, dEdt,dOdt
# Initial conditions vector
y0 = X0,I0,Z0,H0,E0,O0
# Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
ret = odeint(deriv, y0, t)
X, I, Z, H, E, O = ret.T
# Plot the data on three separate curves for S(t), I(t) and R(t)
plt.xlim([-10, 10])
plt.plot(ret[:,4], ret[:,5])
plt.show()
e1=ret[:,4]
e2=ret[:,5]
```

Unfortunately, it produces the following warning:

> File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py", line 247
> warnings.warn(warning_msg, ODEintWarning)
> ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.

And the result is not as expected. I cannot here post graphical result probably.

Does anyone know how I can fix it, please?

Comment: somewhat-tangential, you may find a symbolic solver like sympy and its lambdify will help you here! https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html

Comment: does running with `full_output = 1` as it suggests reveal any more?

Comment: Your solution explodes, either due to division-by-near-zero or due to the cubic terms. The remainder of the requested output is filled with the uninitialized garbage from the array allocation. Is the third group of equations correct or should that be E instead of X everywhere?

Comment: Testing the code, the output array is zero-initialized, and divergence happens at about t=2.53. If that is not expected to happen, then something in the equations or parameters may be wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, I'm not familiar with sympy unfortunately.

I also, have changed the model and parameters the solution gain was not what I expected so I manipulated the model.